# Opening ASCII file in Excel with VBA for multiples files- Loop is running in the same output file Instead of next file

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have multiple ascii files in a folder. I want to open each ascii file with delimiter comma, then I want to do some operation and save the file as Excel work book without overwriting the ascii file. Like this need to do for many files ascii file using macro. Anyone help me write excel macro code.

In the loop need to open the ascii file and do the my job then save the file as Excel file in the **final** folder.then reading next ascii file in the files actually.

But my code is opening the the first ascii file doing the my job, then
saving as new Excel file. Instead of opening the next ascii file, it
is doing the job on the saved Excel file.

```
Sub ProcessFiles()
    Dim Filename, Pathname As String
    Dim wb As Workbook
    
    Pathname = ThisWorkbook.path & "\files\"
    Filename = Dir(Pathname)
    Do While Filename <> ""
            
        Call Workbooks.OpenText(Filename:=Pathname & Filename, DataType:=xlDelimited, Comma:=True)
            
        Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
        DoWork wb
                   
        wb.SaveAs Filename:=wb.path & "\final\" & wb.Name & ".xlsx", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False, ConflictResolution:=True
        wb.Saved = True
        wb.Close
        'wb.Close SaveChanges:=True
        'Filename = Dir(Pathname & "*.xlsx")
        
    Loop
    
    MsgBox "Successfully Completed. Developed By Siddhu"
    
End Sub
    
Sub DoWork(wb As Workbook)
    With wb
        
       
    myjob goes here in each file      
            
      
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: You should at least post you attempts. People may help you with that but it is unlikely that people here are just doing the job for you.

Comment: code added brother

Comment: Much better this way :-). Even better if you can pinpoint the location in the code where things don't go as expected. I'm sorry that personally I can't help you with this, because I'm not really an Excel-macro expert :-/, but I'm sure there will be others.

Comment: VTC, no question and no hint where there might be a problem with the code. And [Anyone help me write excel macro code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) is not a question

Comment: I mentioned my problem  @Storax

Comment: It seems you are missing a call to `Dir` in the lop, i.e. `filename=Dir` before `loop`, see this [eaxmple](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45749626/6600940).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do somthing like that

```
Sub ProcessFiles()
    Dim Filename, Pathname As String
    Dim wb As Workbook
    
    Pathname = ThisWorkbook.path & "\files\"
    Filename = Dir(Pathname)
    Do While Filename <> ""
            
        Call Workbooks.OpenText(Filename:=Pathname & Filename, DataType:=xlDelimited, Comma:=True)
            
        Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
        DoWork wb
                   
        wb.SaveAs Filename:=wb.path & "\final\" & wb.Name & ".xlsx", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False, ConflictResolution:=True
        wb.Saved = True
        wb.Close
        'wb.Close SaveChanges:=True
        'Filename = Dir(Pathname & "*.xlsx")
         
        Filename = Dir     `<=== this will go to the next file in the directory  
    Loop
    
    MsgBox "Successfully Completed. Developed By Siddhu"
    
End Sub
```